# How to active zendloader extension in wamp 5.3

Tags: php

I want to install motocms template in my wamp, but the problem is that it require zendloader extension to be active when installing this template, anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to install MotoCMS to your local server, you need to make sure your WAMP supports Zend extension, which is needed to run MotoCMS templates. Please [download this ZIP folder](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bys99Zy0ybIMaUFGS1Zjclp2T28/view). You will find all the needed install files in order to run WAMP on your Windows 7 computer.